# glob() thinks that a symlink is a folder?

Tags: php

I have found a strange phenomenon in PHP's `glob()` function and I wonder why it happens.

Let's assume I have a folder X with following contents:

```
a.html
b.html
```

Now I have a folder Y which contain a symlink:

```
a.html
b.html -> ../X/b.html
```

When I run following PHP command:

```
glob('Y/*/'); // list all folders in Y
```

I get an array containing "Y/b.html", but I can't explain that, because `b.html` doesn't seem to fit the mask `*/`
Why?

**Update**

My system is a Debian Stretch with PHP 7.0.33, all packages are latest stable.

Here is the whole reproduction procedure:

```
[23:09]root@ras3:/tmp/test$ mkdir X
[23:09]root@ras3:/tmp/test$ mkdir Y
[23:09]root@ras3:/tmp/test$ touch X/a.html
[23:09]root@ras3:/tmp/test$ touch X/b.html
[23:09]root@ras3:/tmp/test$ touch Y/a.html
[23:09]root@ras3:/tmp/test$ cd Y
[23:09]root@ras3:/tmp/test/Y$ ln -s ../X/b.html
[23:09]root@ras3:/tmp/test/Y$ cd ..
[23:09]root@ras3:/tmp/test$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > var_dump(glob('Y/*/'));
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "Y/b.html"
}
php >
<130> [23:10]root@ras3:/tmp/test$ php -v
PHP 7.0.33-0+deb9u3 (cli) (built: Mar  8 2019 10:01:24) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.33-0+deb9u3, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
[23:10]root@ras3:/tmp/test$ uname -a
Linux ras3 4.14.87-v7+ #1178 SMP Tue Dec 11 14:47:38 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: you should use the `GLOB_ONLYDIR` flag to prevent this, if you're only looking to get directories

Comment: Can't reproduce, could you tell us about the php version and OS you are using?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce it either on Mac OS PHP 7.3.0.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. My system is a Debian Stretch with PHP 7.0.33, all packages are latest stable. I could reproduce it on two systems (one x64, one ARM). `GLOB_ONLYDIR` works!